# mask subdomain as a folder in root domain in Plesk Onyx for Centos 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, centos, plesk

I have a rails app running well on my subdomain, which I want accessible by accessing a folder in my root domain. This should be easy, but ive been trying to figure this out all night/day... :(

my setup I would like is this:

```
mydomain.com/store >>> store.mydomain.com
```

I have tried creating a symlink, (which is what I did previously on CPanel) but i keep getting 403 Access Forbidden. I then tried adding the following into *Apache & nginx Settings >> Apache & nginx Settings* to no avail.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs> 
    Options FollowSymLinks 
</Directory>
```

Im at a loss, and need to get this up and running reasonably quickly.

Comment: just for completion, I added a blog post outlining a complete solution here: https://devgypsy.com/rails-app-on-subdomain-in-plesk-onyx/